# MySQL Query - Not Equal to THIS and THIS

Tags: mysql

I'm getting some weird results, so I need to just check myself...

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE complete != 0
AND pending != 1
```

**To be clear, these are allowed:**

```
pending = 0, complete = 0
pending = 1, complete = 1
pending = 0, complete = 1
```

**THis is NOT allowed to be returned from my query:**

```
pending = 1, complete = 0
```

What am I missing here...?

Comment: Is it just that i need parenthesis around `(complete != 0
AND pending != 1)` ?

Comment: You should not need parentheses. That query should work, maybe you should post more detail about the actual query you are running (or the table). If that is the query, word for word, then that is very strange behavior.

Comment: I doubt parens would make a difference. Can you modify your question with the table structure? My first guess would be that either complete or pending weren't int data types

Comment: @LoganSerman nope, that's it...  the answer below was correct.

Comment: @KaiQing Answer below worked.  TINYINT 1 fields.

Comment: Commenters: see David Parvin's answer below. The query as given will "work", it just excludes almost all of the OP's allowable cases.

Comment: Ah, I see... I didn't look closely enough at the actual logic. Was looking more at the query, glad you found your answer.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE NOT (complete = 0
AND pending = 1)
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE !(complete = 0
AND pending = 1)
```

EDIT:
I went and looked at:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/expressions.html

Comment: This. The original clause is *too* restrictive: It only allows `complete = 1; pending = 0`.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use `OR`, not `AND`.  Your expression leaves out any combination where `complete = 0` or `pending = 1`, which is too restrictive.  Try the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE complete != 0 OR pending != 1;
                    ^^ change AND to OR
```

Sample: http://sqlize.com/G8j6sFqo09